# Multiple POST payload structures to Java Spring-MVC REST API

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-mvc, post

I'm not a backend developer but I'm wondering if this is possible, with or without Spring Framework.

My idea is to basically give to an endpoint the ability to receive a JSON either as an object or as an array and deal with both properly.

If its an acceptable single object, handle its creation, and return an object with the primary key (id, for example) associated with it, as the 200 (or 201) response content of the endpoint.

However, if its an array of acceptable objects, iterate over them, as if they were sended individually, and return an array of them with their primary key (id, for example) which is associated with each of them, as the 200 (or 201) response content of the endpoint.

Also, this would be RESTful? I mean, this is an acceptable behavior to give to this HTTP verb?

Comment: Why not define the payload as just array of resources (objects)? And in case of single object just pass array of single resource.

Comment: This can be one strategy to deal with, however, I do not want to remove a known behavior of the verb, avoiding unexpected responses of error from the API. The idea is to increment, expand the verb's ability to create a flexible / dynamic API.

Comment: I don't think it is proper REST interface. For the same verb you want to use different type of nouns. They need to be separated by different URLs. For example do `POST` on `/car/` that returns single id object and `POST` on `/cars/` that returns array of id objects. You can always have your REST interface to accept and return String type and you have to do parsing on your side to deal with different content.

Comment: Actually, the discussion over the noun used on the path is not relevant due to the assumption that is more reliable to use plurals over singulars. Also, you are giving to the noun the responsibility to inform if it accepts something and how it does it (and thats is another assumption, but is wrong in this case). The idea of the nouns on the path are to identify to which entity they refer to. In a similar way, its possible to think that my question leads to the same wrong perspective, but it's not, because POST can deal with singles or collections. Can it accept both?